# error【TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to ... ... 】when using kneed

Tags: python, point

I want to find the elbow point of L-curve for choosing the y-axis-value of elbow point as a threshold. And deleting the points whose y-axis-valye is lower than the threshold. To achieve this, I use the kneed(https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed), a python package for find knee/elbow point.

I wrote the function like this,

```
def findThresholdLCurve(data:dict): 
    if len(data) > 0:
        # 统计所有词语出现的次数并按出现次数降序排序
        Occ = sorted(list(data.values()), reverse=True)

        x = list(range(1, len(data) + 1))
        y = Occ
        kneedle = KneeLocator(x, y, curve="convex", direction="decreasing", online=True,interp_method="polynomial")
        th = kneedle.knee_y
        kneedle.plot_knee() 
        return th
```

Most of data run successfully, and get a appropriate elbow point.Like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTZKy.png)

But，it have some trouble when the data like this,

```
data = {'apple': 0.5966618322834488, 'banana': 0.32877029629550597, 'peach': 0.5540431299774883}
```

The procedure still return a plot, but there is no knee/elbow point,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi3WT.png)
and the error like this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my_study\AUDESOME_py_chatgpt\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    S = cal_S(O1, L)
  File "D:\my_study\AUDESOME_py_chatgpt\cal_S.py", line 43, in cal_S
    th2 = findThresholdLCurve(S[ci])
  File "D:\my_study\AUDESOME_py_chatgpt\findThresholdLCurve.py", line 23, in findThresholdLCurve
    kneedle.plot_knee()  
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kneed\knee_locator.py", line 386, in plot_knee
    plt.vlines(
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3012, in vlines
    return gca().vlines(
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1148, in vlines
    self.update_datalim(corners)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2481, in update_datalim
    if not np.any(np.isfinite(xys)):
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I thought it maybe the value of the data y is too long, so I changed the number of digits after the decimal point to 10, but it still have this problem.

How can I fix it? Or if there's any other way to find an elbow/knee point?

Answer (score 1):

I done.
I find the elbow point of L-Curve by using kneebow(https://github.com/georg-un/kneebow).

The code like this,

```
from kneebow.rotor import Rotor
def function(data):
    rotor = Rotor()  # 实例化一个对象
    rotor.fit_rotate(data)
    elbow_idx = rotor.get_elbow_index()
    if elbow_idx == 0:
        knee_idx = rotor.get_knee_index()
        # rotor.plot_knee()
        return Occ[knee_idx]
    else:
        # rotor.plot_elbow()
        return Occ[elbow_idx]
```

where data is two-dimensional array.